# Possible to force Highcarts to use the circle symbol for all the series in a line graph?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like all the lines to use the same circle symbol.

Here is what i currently have:

```
$TopChartJS = $(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        colors: ["#cc1c0d", "#1d63af" , "#9eb215"],
        chart: {
            type: 'line\,
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)',
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        data: {
            table: 'sheet6'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Cost Comparison'
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickInterval:3,
            title: {
                text: 'Months'
            },
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 3,
                    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: null // inherit from series
                },
                shadow: true
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Cost [kUSD]'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,0);
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: 'Month {point.x}: {point.y} kUSD'
        },

    });
});
```

I have three series in my chart and I would like them all to use the same circle symbol but with different colors.

I have tried adding the plotoptions marker symbol definition to various sections but that does not see to work and the chart doesn't get displayed anymore.

Is this even possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the plot options for the marker to be circle, and it will be used for all series. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyqqbom1/1/)):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }]
});
```